# 2009 Ford E350 Econoline Passenger van OEM Navi upgrade w Ford Sony Factory Amp

Tags: ford, audio, navigation, e350

I purchased used Factory OEM units for my E350 Van, but not sure how the wiring harness attaches from the vehicle to the Amplifier to the Navi.

The Amp is Sony 18B849 and the Navi is OEM Ford Model (1P) NA6W-4205GB Made in Japan. Has built in Satellite and CD Don't think is has Microsoft Sync.

Can anyone tell me how to plug the Three plug Amp plugs in. Need to splice the connectors myself I see they are color coded

Comment: can you provide a vehicle that the units came out of or are used in? can you also provide pictures of the harness plugs or provide a pin count?

Answer (score -1):

pin 1 (sw+ vt-gn)
pin 2(sw-gn-wh) 
...on acm

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! While this might answer the question, I'm not sure how anyone might be understanding what you wrote? Can you clarify your answer with explanation as to what exactly you're talking about?